# Shorten long url string with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, smarty

I'm very new to .htaccess but I seriously need to shorten some of my urls for example

mydomain.com/pet-friendly-cottages.php?**opt40=Yes&opt9=Yes&opt7=9**

is there a way to hide the end part after the question mark with .htaccess?

THIS BIT => opt40=Yes&opt9=Yes&opt7=9

Many thanks  Jase.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Rewrite` like :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^pets/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /pet-friendly-cottages.php.php?opt40=$1&opt9=$2&opt7=$3 [L]
```

then your URLs will looks like : 
`site.com/pets/opt40/opt9/opt7`